# Shapely command error: from shapely.geometry import LineString

Tags: python, error, shapely, linestring, anaconda

I am trying to run a program but getting the following error when I am using the command:

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString
```

> Error: FileNotFoundError: Could not find module
> 'C:\Users\SWWB\Anaconda\Library\bin\geos_c.dll' (or one of its
> dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How did you install shapely?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install geopandas as follow:

```
conda install geopandas
```

Answer (score -1):

Shapely is your interface to GEOS. I'd start troubleshooting by trying to reinstall geopandas via conda so it checks that your dependencies are all there. `conda install geopandas --force-reinstall`